# "bad expression" declare char array c

Tags: c, turbo-c

When I compile my .c file using bcc, I get a bad expression error (shown below), and I have no idea what's causing it.

In main, the following line causes...

```
    char test[13312];
```

... this error

```
kernel.c:25.5: error: bad expression
kernel.c:25.10: error: need ';'
```

Commenting out that line (and lines that use the test array) makes the error go away.

This is all of the code:

```
/* kernel 
 *
 * Register parameters for various BIOS interrupts 
 * http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm
 * 
 * Sector 1: Map
 * Sector 2: Dir
 * Sector 3: Kernel 
 */

void printString(char* chars);
void readString(char* arr);
void readSector(char* buffer, int sector);
void readFile(char* fileName, char* buffer); 

void handleInterrupt21(int ax, int bx, int cx, int dx);

int mod(int a, int b);
int div(int a, int b);

void main(){ 
    printString("helloooo from main");
    //char line[80];
    //char buffer[80];
    char test[13312];
    makeInterrupt21();
    interrupt(0x21,0,"test",0,0); 
    //interrupt(0x21,3,"messag",buffer,0);
    //interrupt(0x21,3,"helloo",line,0); 
    //interrupt(0x21,0,"hello from main",0,0);
    readFile("messag",test);    
    interrupt(0x21,0,test,0,0); 
    //interrupt(0x21,0,line,0,0);
    while(1);
}


// Prints out each character of the array until it reaches 0x0 
// Call using Int 21 w/ ax=0
void printString(char* chars){ 

    int i=0; 

    for(i=0;chars[i]!='\0';i++){ 
        char al = chars[i];
        char ah = 0xe;
        int ax = ah * 256 + al;
        interrupt(0x10, ax, 0, 0, 0);
    }

}

// Reads from keyboard, while updating the display with what is being typed 
// Can deal with backspaces 
// Call using Int 21 w/ ax=1
void readString(char* arr){ 
    char enter = 0xd; 
    char endLine = 0xa; 
    char nullChar = 0x0; 
    char back = 0x8; 

    // while loop set up 
    int i = 0; 
    char ascii = interrupt(0x16, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+ascii, 0, 0, 0);

    // exit key: enter
    while(ascii!=enter){ 

        // decrements i (up to 0) if a backspace is entered, otherwise increments i
        // deals with what is in the char array         
        if(ascii==back&&i>0) {i--;}
        else if(ascii==back) {i=0;} 
        else {arr[i]=ascii; i++;}   

        // get next input letter and write it to screen 
        ascii = interrupt(0x16, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
        interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+ascii, 0, 0, 0);

        // clear the display when backspace is clicked 
        if(ascii==back){
            interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+nullChar, 0, 0, 0);
            interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+ascii, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    // puts end line and null characters at the end of the array 
    arr[i] = endLine; 
    arr[i+1] = nullChar; 


    // Writes a new line character to the screen 
    interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+endLine, 0, 0, 0); 
} 

// Will take a predefined character array of 512 bytes+, and a sector number
// Call using Int 21 w/ ax=2
void readSector(char* buffer, int sector){ 
    int ah = 2; // tells BIOS to read 
    int al = 1; // number of sectors to read 
    int ax = ah * 256 + al; 
    int bx = buffer; // address where the data should be stored to 
    int ch = div(sector,36); //0 // track number 
    int cl = mod(sector,18)+1;  //13; // relative sector number 
    int cx = ch * 256 + cl;     
    int dh = mod(div(sector,18),2); //1; // head number
    int dl = 0; // device number; 0=floppy
    int dx = dh * 256 + dl; 

    //printString(bx);

    interrupt(0x13, ax, bx, cx, dx); 
    //printString((char)buffer);
} 

// Call using Int 21 w/ ax=3
// Not a finished 
void readFile(char* fileName, char* buffer){ 
    printString("entered"); 
    char dir[512];
    readSector(dir,2);
    // p will always be first char of what we're looking at
    int i,j,p;
    i = j = p 
    int flag= 0;    

    while(i<16){
        printString("i-loop");
        j=p;
        while(j<6){
            printString("j-loop");
            if(!dir[j]==fileName[j-p])
                break; 
            j++;
        }
        if(j==5) {flag=1; printString("flag=1"); break;}
        p+=32;
        i++;
    }
    if(flag==0){
        printString("0");
    } else {
        printString("1");
    }

    buffer = flag; 
} 

void handleInterrupt21(int ax, int bx, int cx, int dx){ 
    if(ax==0) {
        // bx = String 
        printString(bx); 
    } else if(ax==1) {
        // bx = buffer to hold read string 
        readString(bx);
    } else if(ax==2) {
        // bx = buffer to hold read string
        // cx = sector number
        readSector(bx,cx); 
    } else if(ax==3) { 
        // bx = char array holding file name
        // cx = address of a buffer to hold the file
        readFile(bx,cx);    
    }  else {
        printString("Invalid use of Int 21\0"); 
    }
} 

// aka a%b
int mod(int a, int b){ 
    while(a>=b)
        a=a-b;
    return a; 
} 

// aka a/b 
int div(int a, int b){ 
    int q = 0; 
    while (a>=b){
        q++;
        a=a-b;
    }
    return q; 
}
```

**Update:**
Fixing the declaration error still causes compilation errors (just in bcc). It seems like the compiler doesn't like any of the variable declarations.

```
    /* kernel 
     *
     * Register parameters for various BIOS interrupts 
     * http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm
     * 
     * Sector 1: Map
     * Sector 2: Dir
     * Sector 3: Kernel 
     */

    void printString(char* chars);
    void readString(char* arr);
    void readSector(char* buffer, int sector);
    void readFile(char* fileName, char* buffer); 

    void handleInterrupt21(int ax, int bx, int cx, int dx);

    int mod(int a, int b);
    int div(int a, int b);

    void main(){ 
        //char line[80];
        //char buffer[80];
        char test[13312];
        makeInterrupt21();
        interrupt(0x21,0,"test",0,0); 
        //interrupt(0x21,3,"messag",buffer,0);
        //interrupt(0x21,3,"helloo",line,0); 
        //interrupt(0x21,0,"hello from main",0,0);
        readFile("messag",test);    
        interrupt(0x21,0,test,0,0); 
        //interrupt(0x21,0,line,0,0);
        while(1);
    }


    // Prints out each character of the array until it reaches 0x0 
    // Call using Int 21 w/ ax=0
    void printString(char* chars){ 

        int i=0; 

        for(i=0;chars[i]!='\0';i++){ 
            char al = chars[i];
            char ah = 0xe;
            int ax = ah * 256 + al;
            interrupt(0x10, ax, 0, 0, 0);
        }

    }

    // Reads from keyboard, while updating the display with what is being typed 
    // Can deal with backspaces 
    // Call using Int 21 w/ ax=1
    void readString(char* arr){ 
        char enter = 0xd; 
        char endLine = 0xa; 
        char nullChar = 0x0; 
        char back = 0x8; 

        // while loop set up 
        int i = 0; 
        char ascii = interrupt(0x16, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+ascii, 0, 0, 0);

        // exit key: enter
        while(ascii!=enter){ 

            // decrements i (up to 0) if a backspace is entered, otherwise increments i
            // deals with what is in the char array         
            if(ascii==back&&i>0) {i--;}
            else if(ascii==back) {i=0;} 
            else {arr[i]=ascii; i++;}   

            // get next input letter and write it to screen 
            ascii = interrupt(0x16, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
            interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+ascii, 0, 0, 0);

            // clear the display when backspace is clicked 
            if(ascii==back){
                interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+nullChar, 0, 0, 0);
                interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+ascii, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        // puts end line and null characters at the end of the array 
        arr[i] = endLine; 
        arr[i+1] = nullChar; 


        // Writes a new line character to the screen 
        interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+endLine, 0, 0, 0); 
    } 

    // Will take a predefined character array of 512 bytes+, and a sector number
    // Call using Int 21 w/ ax=2
    void readSector(char* buffer, int sector){ 
        int ah = 2; // tells BIOS to read 
        int al = 1; // number of sectors to read 
        int ax = ah * 256 + al; 
        int bx = buffer; // address where the data should be stored to 
        int ch = div(sector,36); //0 // track number 
        int cl = mod(sector,18)+1;  //13; // relative sector number 
        int cx = ch * 256 + cl;     
        int dh = mod(div(sector,18),2); //1; // head number
        int dl = 0; // device number; 0=floppy
        int dx = dh * 256 + dl; 

        //printString(bx);

        interrupt(0x13, ax, bx, cx, dx); 
        //printString((char)buffer);
    } 

    // Call using Int 21 w/ ax=3
    // Not finished 
    void readFile(char* fileName, char* buffer){ 
        printString("entered"); 
        char dir[512];
        readSector(dir,2);
        // p will always be first char of what we're looking at
        int i,j,p; 
        i = j = p = 0; 
        while(i<16){
            printString("i-loop");
            j=p;
            while(j<6){
                printString("j-loop");
                if(!dir[j]==fileName[j-p])
                    break; 
                j++;
            }
            if(j==5) {flag=1; printString("flag=1"); break;}
            p+=32;
            i++;
        }
        if(flag==0){
            printString("0");
        } else {
            printString("1");
        }

        buffer = flag; 
    } 

    void handleInterrupt21(int ax, int bx, int cx, int dx){ 
        if(ax==0) {
            // bx = String 
            printString(bx); 
        } else if(ax==1) {
            // bx = buffer to hold read string 
            readString(bx);
        } else if(ax==2) {
            // bx = buffer to hold read string
            // cx = sector number
            readSector(bx,cx); 
        } else if(ax==3) { 
            // bx = char array holding file name
            // cx = address of a buffer to hold the file
            readFile(bx,cx);    
        }  else {
            printString("Invalid use of Int 21\0"); 
        }
    } 

    // aka a%b
    int mod(int a, int b){ 
        while(a>=b)
            a=a-b;
        return a; 
    } 

    // aka a/b 
    int div(int a, int b){ 
        int q = 0; 
        while (a>=b){
            q++;
            a=a-b;
        }
        return q; 
    }
```

Errors:

```
 kernel.c:119.6: error: bad expression
 kernel.c:119.10: error: need ';'
 kernel.c:119.11: error: dir undeclared
 kernel.c:119.15: error: illegal indirection
 kernel.c:122.5: error: bad expression
 kernel.c:122.7: error: need ';'
 kernel.c:122.8: error: i undeclared
 kernel.c:122.10: error: j undeclared
 kernel.c:122.12: error: p undeclared
 kernel.c:129.14: error: illegal indirection
 kernel.c:133.18: error: flag undeclared
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` on `i = j = p` but that might not be the problem.

Comment: @Nick why that might not be a problem?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im It is *a* problem, but it might not be *the* problem ;-)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, What Nikos said is what I meant :)

Comment: Is this supposed to be some kind of embedded or DOS real-mode code? If yes, you should specifically mention it, as well as the compiler you're using.

Comment: @NikosC. thanks. That proves I have very little knowledge about English

Comment: @Nick Though it probably *is* the problem, so you might want to post an actual answer.

Comment: Maybe that compiler is so old it doesn't even understand line-end comments ( the `//` variety)...

Comment: @NikosC. took your advice thanks :)

Comment: Does your compiler permit mixed declarations and statements within a block? What happens if you move the declaration `char test[13312];` *before* the call `printString("helloooo from main");`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many warnings about things like assigning integers to pointers; but the only compile error is that you are missing a `;` after `i = j = p`.

There aren't any errors on the declaration of `test` or near to it.

Comment: That was a good catch, however, changing the declaration still leaves some compilation errors (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but are you on a machine with an 8-bit `size_t`? If yes, 13312 would result in 0 due to overflow. So in effect, you have:

```
char test[0];
```

which would explain the error. Please show the output of:

```
printf("%u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(size_t));
```

Comment: A conforming implementation can't make `size_t` that small. And I added a cast to the `sizeof` expression so the types match.

Comment: @KeithThompson Hm, indeed. Though the fact that 13312 results exactly in 0 when casted to a `uint8_t` or `int8_t` still bugs me. Quite the coincidence there.

Comment: 13312 is 0x3400; in programming terms, it's a round number.

Comment: @KeithThompson Still a weird coincidence :)

Comment: There's nothing weird or coincidental about an array size being a multiple of 256, and that certainly wouldn't explain the error, which is complaining about syntax. Keith's hypothesis that the compiler doesn't allow declarations to be interspersed with statements is far more plausible.

Comment: @JimBalter Which is why the question began with "just a shot in the dark", in case you missed it.

Comment: The fact is that, even if your shot in the dark had been correct and size_t were 8 and the compiler were truncating 13312 to 0 without comment (which would be nonconforming and stupid), that still wouldn't explain the error message ... nor would it cause all numbers that are multiples of 256 to be weird coincidences. That's logic and good sense ... in case you're missing it.